# Change canvas size without scaling images

Tags: c#

Any idea how to change canvas size without scaling images? Here is what I have tried.

```
<Canvas ClipToBounds="True" Name="ImageDropShadowThumbnail" Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}">
<Canvas.LayoutTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Value, ElementName=ScaleXSlider}" ScaleY="{Binding Value, ElementName=ScaleYSlider}" CenterX="{Binding CenterX}" CenterY="{Binding CenterY}"/>
</Canvas.LayoutTransform>
<Image Source="{Binding Name}" Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="{Binding Value, ElementName=BlurRadiusSlider}" Direction="{Binding Value, ElementName=DirectionSlider}" Opacity="{Binding Value, ElementName=OpacitySlider}" ShadowDepth="{Binding Value, ElementName=ShadowDepthSlider}"/>
    </Image.Effect>
</Image>
```

Comment: Are you using WPF?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen yes.

Comment: I see that you're binding the `Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}"` on what are you binding? The window/control?

Comment: What if you replace this binding for a constant value. like: `Height="200" Width="100"`